# How to do a loop to process two input files

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I am using awk to do match two files and then multiply the elements of file2 and file1.

```
 awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1]=$2; b[$1]=$3; next}
      /:/ || !NF{print; next}
     {print $1, $2*a[$1], $2*b[$1]}' file2 file1 > output
```

This script only process two input files and produce one output file.

I want to do a loop to use this script for many (thousands ) files. I try to do:

```bsh
for file1 in ../mo/*e.log | 
for file2 in ../excited/*-d.log;   do
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1]=$2; b[$1]=$3; next}
     /:/ || !NF{print; next}
     {print $1, $2*a[$1], $2*b[$1]}' "$file1" "$file2" > "${file1%e.log}f.log"
done
```

The files are related, so are like 0001e.log and 0001-d.log, 0002e.log and 0002-d.log, 0002e.log and 0002-d.log ... The expected output could be 0001f.log , 0002f.log , 0003f.log ...

But with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show input and expected output.

Comment: What does "with no success" mean, exactly? You mention "match" in the first sentence but I see no evidence of that in your code: do you want to run the awk command for all NxM combinations of `e.log` and `-d.log` files, or only for specific pairs? if the latter, how are the filenames related?

Comment: @steeldriver, I want to run the awk command for specific pairs. The filenames are related, so the names are 0001e.log and 0001-d.log ,  0002e.log and 0002-d.log ,  0003e.log and 0003-d.log  ....

Comment: Then you need only a single loop - please see [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288726/65304)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want:

```bsh
set ../mo/*e.log
for file2 in ../excited/*-d.log; do
  file1=$1; shift
  awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1]=$2; b[$1]=$3; next}
       /:/ || !NF{print; next}
       {print $1, $2*a[$1], $2*b[$1]}' "$file1" "$file2" > "${file1%e.log}f.log"
done
```

Or with `zsh`:

```bsh
file1s=(../mo/*e.log)
file2s=(../excited/*-d.log)
for file1 file2 (${file1s:^file2s}) {
  awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1]=$2; b[$1]=$3; next}
       /:/ || !NF{print; next}
       {print $1, $2*a[$1], $2*b[$1]}' "$file1" "$file2" > "${file1%e.log}f.log"
}
```

Above, we've got 2 sorted lists of file names and we go through both lists in parallel. If the base name of the files in `mo` and in `excited` are to be matched instead, you could do:

```bsh
for file1 in ../mo/*e.log; do
  basename=${file1%e.log}
  basename=${basename##*/}
  file2=../excited/$basename-d.log
  [ -f "$file2" ] || continue
  awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1]=$2; b[$1]=$3; next}
       /:/ || !NF{print; next}
       {print $1, $2*a[$1], $2*b[$1]}' "$file1" "$file2" > "${file1%e.log}f.log"
done
```

Comment: The last aswer has an error when I tried to test it. line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `basename=${file1%e.log}'

Comment: @allopp, there was a missing `do`.

Comment: I dont know but now the last script works but not output anything?

Comment: @allopp, another obvious mistake. There may be more as I've not tested the solution. You know you're allowed to try and understand and debug the answers. That's not a free solution spoon-feeding service.

Answer (score 2):

Try `paste file1 file2 | tr '\t' '*' | bc > output`.

Then for the big loop (with **bash**), which lines up files from *../mo/*, *../excited/*, and outputs products to **f** series of numbered files in current directory:

```bash
for f in ../mo/*e.log; do
    g=${f/mo/excited}
    o=${f##*/}
    paste $f ${g/e.log/-d.log} | tr '\t' '*' | bc > ${o/e.log/f.log} 
done
```

---

Demo, (with **bash**isms), print the squares of 1-5:

```
paste <(seq 5) <(seq 5) | tr '\t' '*' | bc
```

Output:

```
1
4
9
16
25
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel installed you can do:

```
doit() {
  file1="$1"
  file2="$2"
  output="$3"
  awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1]=$2; b[$1]=$3; next}
      /:/ || !NF{print; next}
     {print $1, $2*a[$1], $2*b[$1]}' "$file2" "$file1" > "$output"
}
export -f doit

# If all filenames fit on a command line:
parallel --xapply doit {1} {2} {1/.}{2/.}.out ::: ../mo/?*e.log ::: ../excited/?*d.log
# With newer versions you can do:
parallel  doit {1} {2} {1/.}{2/.}.out ::: ../mo/?*e.log :::+ ../excited/?*d.log

# If you do not like the {/.} you can do:
parallel doit {1} '{= s/e.log/d.log/;s:/mo/:/excited/:; =}' '{=s/.log/.out/;s:^../mo/::;=}' ::: ../mo/?*e.log

# If all the files do not fit on the command line (because you have thousands):
finda() { find ../mo/ -name '*e.log'; }
findb() { find ../excited/ -name '*d.log'; }

parallel --xapply doit {1} {2} {1/.}{2/.}.out :::: <(finda) <(findb)
parallel doit {1} {2} {1/.}{2/.}.out :::: <(finda) ::::+ <(findb)
finda | parallel doit {1} '{= s/e.log/d.log/;s:/mo/:/excited/:; =}' '{=s/.log/.out/;s:^../mo/::;=}'
```

It will run one job per core. If you prefer one job at a time, replace `parallel` with `parallel -j1`.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel